# ssh-copy-id does not work

Tags: ssh

I know this issue has been discussed already. I looked at the other threads, and didn't find a question with the same issue, hope you could help me...

I SSH from **userA@hostA** to **userB@hostB**. Both hosts using the same file-system, meaning that userA's home is the same on hostA and hostB, and the same with userB's home.

Now, I wanted to save the key on B's .ssh dir, so I could access from A@A to B@B without a password, so I did the following on userA@hostA:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa userB@hostB
echo $? ### output was 0, meaning it was successfull    
ssh -v userB@hostB
```

And got the following output:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to hostB [100.100.100.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/userA/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'hostB' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/userA/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_524' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_524' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_524' not found

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userA/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/userA/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userA/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/userA/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
userB@hostB's password:
```

Note that I did manage to have a password-free access to userA@hostB, but not when accessing userB...

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

PS. some additional info:

hostA version:

> Linux version 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64
>   (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red
>   Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015

hostB version:

> Linux version 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
>   (mockbuild@x86-022.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7
>   20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Jan 29 11:47:41 EST 2013

on userB@hostB (I assume that's what Jakuje meant), access of dirs and files:

```
~: drwxrwx---  
~/.ssh: drwx------  
~/.ssh/authorized_keys: -rw-------
```

Comment: first of all, check the server log (if you have access to it). Then update your question with the information what distro are you using on `hostA` and `hostB`. Also update the question with information about the permissions on your `~`, `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server: `ls -l ~ ~/.ssh ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: `sh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa` ... Did you mean `-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`? Newer versions add the `.pub` automatically, but you're on an old version.

Comment: @muru - By mistake, I forgot the .pub (I have both files). I tried now with the .pub extension, but no change, it still asks for PW on every su :(